# How to solve "unhandled exception" issue while updating text field in asp.net core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have updated the edit function in core to update any field based on the necessity. There are 2 fields to update. One is file name other one is image file. Updating the image file only or with the name no issue but if I want to update name only then "unhandled exception" occured.

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("ImgID,Title,ImageFile")] IFormFile fileobj, imageModels imgModels, string fileName, int id)
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(imageModels imgModels, int id, IFormFile ImageFile)
    {
        var imageModels = await _context.Images.FindAsync(id);

        if (ImageFile != null)
        {
           
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", imageModels.ImgName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
            _context.Images.Remove(imageModels);
       
            string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgModels.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(imgModels.ImageFile.FileName);
            imgModels.ImgName = fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/images/", fileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //await imgModels.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                imgModels.ImageFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
 
        }

        _context.Update(imgModels);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        //return View(imgModels);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing your `imageModels` from your context and the you update `imageModels` at the end. Now in your context u have 2 models with same primary key and context is already tracking one that has been removed and will be removed from db when you save changes .

Comment: The code is working while updating both fields, name and file. This error occurred only when updating the file name, not the image file.